# Mirror Modifier Intersection On Small Object

Tags: scale, mirror-modifier

The mirror modifier makes my object intersect with the other side of it which is made by the modifier.
When I scale my object up it fixes the issue, but I need my model to be small with the modifier not applied...
Thanks in advance.
P.S. The origin is at the correct place, and when I apply the mirror it gets fixed too. [image: Intersection + Subdivision Surface modifier]

Comment: Have you enabled the modifier's Clipping option?

Comment: Yeah I did, doesn't work either.

Comment: maybe share your file or at least this small part? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: The issue is at the tip of the knife.
https://pasteall.org/blend/d478683104ea490f80a63bb949a24a2f

Comment: it must be the order of your modifiers, what about putting the Subdivision Surface after the Mirror?

Comment: Yeah, that fixes the issue.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your modifiers messes up the vertices, put the *Subdivision Surface* after the *Mirror* modifier.